# Dual Booting 14.04 and Windows 8.1 on Sony Vaio Tap 20

Tags: 14.04, dual-boot, uefi, boot-repair, vaio

I have been toiling away the last week trying to get 14.04 to dual boot on my Sony Vaio Tap 20.  This is the method I used to install:

1. Disable fast boot, disable secure boot
2. LiveUSB install of Ubuntu with partitions / , /swap, and /home (no boot partition)
3. Attempted to run boot-repair using:

   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair

   sudo apt-get update

   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && (boot-repair &)

then I get this after doing recommended repair:

```
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 33: hash: gksudo: not found
/usr/share/boot-sav/gui-g2slaunch.sh: line 35: hash: gksu: not found
```

4. Even after going into windows and doing this which didn't help:

> bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\grubx64.efi
>   
>   I think what I need to do is force the windows boot manager to use grub.  However, I'm not sure how to do that.  Do I mount sda3 (windows efi boot partition) and copy grub over?  Such as:

```
sudo mount -t vfat /dev/sda3 /mnt
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.bkp
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi /mnt/EFI/Microsoft
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/MicrosoftBoot/bootmgfw.efi
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/Boot/bootx64.efi.grb
sudo cp /mnt/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi /mnt/EFI/MicrosoftBoot/bootmgfw.efi.grb
update-grub
```

Got this from [UEFI still boots directly into Windows 8 instead of GRUB]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2101840

Not sure why boot-repair doesn't work.  Any ideas?  I realize there are a million variations on this question, however, also wondering if I should just reinstall but make a /boot partition during install to save the trouble.

It is very frustrating that boot-repair does not work.

UPDATE:

So, I have another question for how to go about manually moving the Grub boot manager.  When I installed ubuntu, I did not specify a /boot partition.  However, will the installer have installed the grub boot manager package?  The reason I ask is, the windows boot manager will be in sda3, however, the ubuntu boot manager will not have installed to that partition, under which partition would it have installed?  My / partition? (that looks odd, but out of the three, "/" , "/swap" and "/home" that is the one I mean)  I'll need to mount both sda3 and the partition with ubuntu in order to copy grub over.  It has been years since I did any serious linux work and back then I used a sun system.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same problem I used to press F2 and the windows boot manager allowed me to chose the Grub and then Ubuntu. Try all the Fcommands and c if that works for you.
You don't need to disable secure boot as Ubuntu is recognised by your Bios as  asecure OS